# How do I install the new cloth brush

Tags: cloth-simulation

I recently saw that the cloth brush is now open for people to use, but I don't know how to get it?

Comment: Download the 2.83 alpha https://builder.blender.org/download/

Comment: @FFeller I already have, but I can't see the brush in the sculpting tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the following link to download Blender 2.83 Beta from the official website (It's still experimental).

Download link: https://builder.blender.org/download/blender-2.83-ff1040c6fefc-windows64.zip

After downloading, Open blender and go to **sculpture** tab and you will find the brush in the left menu (T menu).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [cloth brush](https://developer.blender.org/D6715) a feature that is currently in development and therefore not yet included in any release or nightly builds. The differential still needs to be reviewed by other developers before it will be included.

There are two ways to test this feature, either you build Blender yourself with the patch applied or you can [download the build](https://blender.community/c/graphicall/Sjbbbc/) created by [LazyDodo](https://developer.blender.org/p/LazyDodo/) from GraphicAll.

Comment: I've installed the build by lazy dodo, but what do I do next.